# How to send custom token with metamask API in web

Tags: javascript, jquery, metamask

```
const transactionParameters = {
  nonce: '0x00', // ignored by MetaMask
  gasPrice: '0x09184e72a000', // customizable by user during MetaMask confirmation.
  gas: '0x2710', // customizable by user during MetaMask confirmation.
  to: '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000', // Required except during contract publications.
  from: ethereum.selectedAddress, // must match user's active address.
  value: '0x00', // Only required to send ether to the recipient from the initiating external account.
  data:
    '0x7f7465737432000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000600057', // Optional, but used for defining smart contract creation and interaction.
  chainId: '0x3', // Used to prevent transaction reuse across blockchains. Auto-filled by MetaMask.
};

// txHash is a hex string
// As with any RPC call, it may throw an error
const txHash = await ethereum.request({
  method: 'eth_sendTransaction',
  params: [transactionParameters],
});
```

How to send custom token or USDT with this code. I am integrating metamask API with JavaScript so please help me out. I am in learning stage no experience with Blockchain.

Comment: Hi. Please be clearer on what you want your code to do.